# axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, face-detection

I am working with Face Recognition in python. I have a following program to recognition my profile.

```
import face_recognition

# Load some images to compare against
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("IMG_2051.JPG")

# Get the face encodings for the known images
face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]

# Load a test image and get encondings for it
image_to_test = face_recognition.load_image_file("manushi.jpg")
image_to_test_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_to_test)[0]

# See how far apart the test image is from the known faces
face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(face_encoding, image_to_test_encoding)

for i, face_distance in enumerate(face_distances):
    print("The test image has a distance of {:.2} from known image #{}".format(face_distance, i))
    print("- With a normal cutoff of 0.6, would the test image match the known image? {}".format(face_distance < 0.6))
    print("- With a very strict cutoff of 0.5, would the test image match the known image? {}".format(face_distance < 0.5))
    print()
```

But, I getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(face_encoding, image_to_test_encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 70, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2198, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Please someone help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct, the `face_distance` function takes an array as the first argument, hence `face_encoding` needs to be passed as an array:

`face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance([face_encoding], image_to_test_encoding)`

In the [face_distance sample script](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/7e454d7a28a06a886313c2a2a68bf11dee57d95b/examples/face_distance.py) provided on the face_recognition github repo you can see that the input for `face_encoding` is an array.

I have also tested passing `face_encoding` as an array and it works.